# How does 子 come to mean 'midnight'?

Tags: characters

[Arch Chinese](https://www.archchinese.com/chinese_english_dictionary.html?find=%E5%AD%90) lists the meanings of 子 as

> son, seed, egg, child, small thing, noun suffix(zi5), midnight, Kangxi radical number 39, 1st terrestrial branch

The meanings of child, egg, diminutive noun suffix etc. are clearly related, but I find it hard to remember that this also means midnight (in particular in the Korean 자정/子正).

How does 子 come to mean 'midnight'? Is it related to the fact that it also stands for '1st terrestrial branch'?

Comment: 旧时计时单位时辰，一天被分成12个时辰，12个时辰对应12个地支。第一个时辰是23:00~01:00，也叫子时。

Comment: Hi @tsh - I'm afraid I don't actually read Chinese - my interest in the characters is through learning Korean.

Comment: 时辰 is an old time unit, 1时辰=2hours. A day is divided into 12 时辰 and we use 12地支(Earthly Branches) to name them. The first 时辰 in a day is from 23:00 to 01:00, which is called 子时.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like that could be an answer to this question, unless you think there's already a duplicate answer on the site somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is indeed related to the [terrestrial (earthly) branches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthly_Branches), and in a 24-hour day,「子時」represents the time of day between 11:00 PM to 1:00 AM.「子正」, as noted in the question, specifically represents *midnight* (12:00 AM).

Unfortunately, there is no convenient mnemonic or etymology that you can use to make a connection between「子」and *midnight*, but I doubt that *midnight* shows up very often anyway as a meaning (unless you're into traditional Korean timekeeping?).

Comment: I guess you could even say that 子 doesn't really "mean midnight", it's just a somewhat lazy/abbreviated way of explaining the notion behind 子时、子正

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you should find some comparative charts of Chinese Zodiac/Earthly Branches to help you to remember them: 
[image]

Comment: It fits rather well into modern-day alcohol-induced-clubbing-weekend culture that the hours between 1 and 3 in the morning should be the _ugly hours_ (in the PRC, at least). Though I guess for most, the real ugliness tends to be the following morning…

Comment: In Traditional Chinese Character, the earthly brach 丑 and 醜 (ugly) are two different characters...

Comment: Hence why I said “in the PRC”, where simplified characters are used.